# How to force Eclipse to use specific version of NodeJS to fix error "Node.js version could not be determined"?

Tags: node.js, eclipse, macos, wildwebdeveloper

I've installed latest version of Eclipse-IDE (2020-03) with installer option "Eclipse IDE for Web and JavaScript Developers". It is very slow. It takes 2-3 seconds to open a file. And finally following error is shown:
[image: Error Node.JS version could not be determined.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Culprit is actually Eclipse Wild Web Developer. It cannot find my NodeJS install done with Homebrew. To fix, I have executed :

```
cd /Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse
echo -Dorg.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.nodeJSLocation=$(which node) >> eclipse.ini
```

Comment: thanks. I don't have any node js don't need it. I installed Eclipse for java EE, however, I have the same error. May you please advice on getting rid of this warning.

Comment: in Eclipse 2020 i go to `~/eclipse/jee-2020-06/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse`

Answer (score 0):

SpringToolSuite4 is as follows:

```
cd /Applications/SpringToolSuite4.app/Contents/Eclipse
echo -Dorg.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.nodeJSLocation=$(which node) >> SpringToolSuite4.ini
```